# Is tf.tranpose(a) in tf.matmul slower than the transpose_a=True argument?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, linear-algebra

I'm new to tensorflow, and was just playing around with the different basic functions and comparing their speed (i.e., `tf.add(A,B)` is faster than `A + B`).

In the case of carrying out the transpose of a vector/matrix for matrix multiplication, would applying `tf.transpose(X)` cause the overall output to be slower as compared to utilizing the built-in argument `transpose_a=True`?

Here's how I compared between the 2 methods:

**Small Matrix Size**

```
# Initialize some random variables
X = tf.random.normal((3,2),dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.random.normal((3,2),dtype=tf.float32)

# Test using the built-in transpose argument
%timeit -r10 -n 10000 tf.matmul(a=X, b=Y, transpose_a=True)
Output: "35.2 µs ± 3.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)"

# Test transposing manually
%timeit -r10 -n 10000 tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), Y)
Output: "325 µs ± 42.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)"
```

**Large Matrix Size** (Smaller loop size)

```
# Initialize some random variables
X = tf.random.normal((5040,1000),dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.random.normal((5040,2139),dtype=tf.float32)

# Test using the built-in transpose argument
%timeit -r10 -n 1000 tf.matmul(a=X, b=Y, transpose_a=True)
Output: "10.4 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)"

# Test transposing manually
%timeit -r10 -n 1000 tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), Y)
Output: "11.2 ms ± 1.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) "
```

From the 2 tests, it seems that there is a noticeable difference between the 2 methods when the matrix sizes are relatively small. On the other hand, these 2 methods are roughly equivalent in speed when the matrix sizes are bumped up.

Why would there by a difference in runtime between the 2 methods when sample size varies? (Tensorflow 2.8 is running on my GPU for both methods)